# host returns 0 for a non existing name

Tags: dns, exit-status

`host` usually returns `0` for existing hosts

```
$ host www.google.com ; echo $?
www.google.com has address 172.217.16.132
www.google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:400a:805::2004
0
```

and `1` in case of errors

```
$ host does.not.exist ; echo $?
Host does.not.exist not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
1
```

I have now a non existing host where `host` returns 0 without any output

```
$ host red3.ethz.ch; echo $?
0
```

`nslookup` generates an error (as expected):

```
$ nslookup red3.ethz.ch
Server:     129.132.98.12
Address:    129.132.98.12#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find red3.ethz.ch: No answer
```

With `-d` and `-v` I see no `ANSWER` section in the output

```
$ host -v -d red3.ethz.ch
Trying "red3.ethz.ch"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55752
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;red3.ethz.ch.          IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ethz.ch.        246 IN  SOA dummy-ns.ethz.ch. hostmaster.ethz.ch. 2008016728 10800 3600 1814400 600

Received 86 bytes from 129.132.98.12#53 in 30 ms
Trying "red3.ethz.ch"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 31530
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;red3.ethz.ch.          IN  AAAA

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ethz.ch.        246 IN  SOA dummy-ns.ethz.ch. hostmaster.ethz.ch. 2008016728 10800 3600 1814400 600

Received 86 bytes from 129.132.98.12#53 in 0 ms
Trying "red3.ethz.ch"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 43023
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;red3.ethz.ch.          IN  MX

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ethz.ch.        246 IN  SOA dummy-ns.ethz.ch. hostmaster.ethz.ch. 2008016728 10800 3600 1814400 600

Received 86 bytes from 129.132.98.12#53 in 0 ms
```

**Why does `host` return 0?**

**Edit**

Looking at the comment it seems that we can narrow it down to a different configuration on the DNS.

On the same domain (`ethz.ch`)

```
$ host doesnotexist.ethz.ch; echo $?
Host doesnotexist.ethz.ch not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
1
$ host red3.ethz.ch; echo $?
0
$ host www.ethz.ch; echo $?
www.ethz.ch has address 129.132.19.216
www.ethz.ch has IPv6 address 2001:67c:10ec:4380::216
0
```

It seems as the response without an IP is considered OK by 'hosts' but not by 'nslookup'.

Comment: Note you might prefer to use `getent hosts red3.ethz.ch` which has a return code 2 for that name.

Comment: @meuh I am on OS X which does not provide `getent`. I am now using nslookup but I am still curious on why the return code is "wrong".

Answer (score 2):

Look, according to `tshark`, **DNS servers return different protocol messages** for your domain names. For `does.not.exist` you receive `DNS 149 Standard query response 0x0d51 No such name`. For `red3.ethz.ch` you receive `Standard query response 0xe4db` and 0 answers. What is why host returns different codes.

As for resolving does.not.exist a DNS server response is:

```
DNS 149 Standard query response 0x0d51 No such name
```

---

As for `red3.ethz.ch` `tshark` shows that a DNS server responds just 0 records in the Answer section:

This is tshark:

```
DNS 128 Standard query response 0xe4db
```

This is host response:

```
Trying "red3.ethz.ch"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 1542
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
```

Comment: How is it valid without returning any records?

Comment: `host cii.cuonglm.xyz` return `Host cii.cuonglm.xyz not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)` but `cuonglm.xyz` is a valid, registered domain.

Comment: @roaima, it has records. Please, see: `$ host www.ethz.ch; echo $?
www.ethz.ch has address 129.132.19.216
www.ethz.ch has IPv6 address 2001:67c:10ec:4380::216
0`

Comment: I don't see any records for `red3`. I see them for `www`, and I get NXDOMAIN for `zzz` but just SERVFAIL for `red3` itself.

Comment: @ cuonglm, a dns server returns for cii.cuonglm.xyz `DNS 149 Standard query response 0x2c83 No such name`. That is why you see not found and return code 1

Comment: @skwllsp: yes, I want to show you that the invalid or valid domain is not relevant here.